# Removing some specific characters from Matlab strings

Tags: matlab

I have recently started programming in MATLAB to create some utilities for myself. I want to create a graphical interface for solving equations.

In the command line I can achieve this simply by:

```
syms x
result = solve('12*x=24');

( and result is going to be = 2 )
```

I wanted to improve this process by creating a GUI.

The current program I have looks like this:

```
function [ output_args ] = SolveEq( equation )
    syms x a b;
    output_args = solve( equation );

end
```

This works only for equation that work on `x`, `a` and `b` variables. I want to process the string as follows:

1. Remove the whitespaces. I found how to achieve this [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html).
2. Get the variables out of that string.

   for example: in string `'12+a-b=0'`, I want my program to be able to find that `a` and `b` are variables, and also perfom the `syms` operation for them.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using works without declaring symbolic variables:

```
f=solve('12*x=24');
```

Working with expressions instead of strings require to declare symbolic variables:

```
syms x
f=solve(12*x==2);
```

Use strings, then nothing must be done.

Code you need after solving:

```
if isstruct(f)
  %more than one variable
  names=fieldnames(f);
else
  %only one variable, f is the solution
end
```